# Basic: calculating a satellites height from its angular speed

Tags: orbital-motion, astronomy, satellites

A few days ago, while loooking at the night sky, I saw a satellite and I wondered if it would be possible to tell how far it is just by looking at it. The only possible naked-eye measurement that I could come up with was its angular speed (for example, how long it takes to traverse a 5 degree arc over your head).

At first, it seemed relatively simple and I got $$ h = R + (GMT^2\theta^{-2})^{1/3}$$ where $h$ is height, $R$ the radius of the Earth, $M$ its mass, $G$ the gravitional constant, $T$ the time it takes to traverse said arc and $\theta$ the angle in radians.

There is just one problem: this angle is measured from the center of the Earth. Given that $R$ is over 6000km (the ISS orbits at around $h=$400km), the angular speed $\theta T^{-1}$ measured from the center of the Earth is going to be significantly different than the one measured from its surface.

I am having trouble incorporating this into my calculation and would welcome any help.

To simplify the problem, let's assume that:

1)We are only interested in satellites that orbit below geostationay orbits. Also, only in satellites that are sufficiently below geostationary orbits for a regular observer to notice their movement against the stars.

2)We can disregard the effect of Earth's rotation (in the few seconds that it takes the satellite to traverse the arc, the stars have barely moved).

3)We only take into account satellites flying directly over our head (or at least, close enough).

PS: it is important that its height can be determined with rudimentary equipment (an extended arm to measure angles and a stopwatch). I am not interested in precise results.

Answer (score 1):

Instantaneous angular speed will not give you sufficient information to fully determine the satellite's orbit. To fully specify a satellite's motion 6 [orbital elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_elements) are required. That means that 6 independent variables need to be measured to solve for the 6 unknowns. In orbit determination, these measurements may include ranges, range-rates, azimuth, elevation, and angular speeds.

The complexity of the problem can be reduced by assuming a circular orbit (eccentricity = 0, roughly true for most LEO orbits). Even so, it will not be the case that each angular velocity corresponds to a unique orbit altitude. As any satellite rises above the horizon, makes its closest approach, and sets below the horizon its angular speed will vary. Multiple angular speed measurements at different times or combination with azimuth and elevation information would be required.

One (unlikely) case where you would be able to use angular speed to compute altitude would be where the satellite passed directly overhead. In this case $v = \dot{\theta} h = \sqrt{\frac{G M}{R+h} }$, which can be rearranged to give a cubic equation for $h$.